# Clutch slave/master cylinder

Tags: nissan, clutch, leak, sentra

I just finished replacing the clutch master cylinder and slave cylinder. The first slave cylinder I installed, fluid starting leaking from the connecting point of the transmission to the engine. I took it apart again and replaced the slave cylinder again. I just put it all back together and its leaking again from the same place. It started leaking as I was filling up the reservoir, I never even pressed the clutch pedal down. Can it be the master cylinder? Is fluid supposed to be sent to the slave cylinder without pushing in the clutch pedal? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Its a 2015 Nissan Sentra with a concentric slave cylinder.

Comment: There is always supposed to be fluid in the line and behind the piston in the slave.  So the fact that it's leaking means there is a problem and it's likely at the slave end of this, not the master.  Assuming you purchased new slave cylinders, I'm going to guess that you didn't get two defective ones and the problem is in the line or the connection.  You may want to check it out before you install it and make sure it's holding fluid and if leaking, you can see where the leak is coming from.

Comment: Is this the same design as your clutch? - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kb5NONrgIl0

Comment: [This appears to be your slave cylinder.](https://www.rockauto.com/info/797/LK_5100164100_Fro__ra_p.jpg) If so, where is it leaking from? From one of the two tube connection points? Or is it leaking up front by where the throwout bearing is at? If one of the two tube connection points, are you sure the tubes are fully seated? There should be a physical click into place on these, where the spring is pushed out of the way and then pops back into place. If it is doing this and is still leaking, is there an o-ring inside by the where the spring clip is at? It needs a seal to work right.